# How husky works?

Tags: git, githooks, husky

https://github.com/typicode/husky has the ability to run git hooks automatically in a way that they can be shared between teams in the repository it self.

How can this even work? Since the hooks need to be in `.git/hooks` which is not added to repository.

Does it wraps `git` command and intercept commands, running hooks when they happen?

I want to reproduce this behavior for python and php projects without the need to depend on npm or node.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? I'm not a javascript expert, but it looks to me that husky installs the hooks when you install it.

Comment: I was trying that. At https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/f955c07cd75a4dd44dd0ec053add07d8e57b8ca6/src/installer/index.ts

Comment: It seems to copy the hooks at `createHook` at above link. This seems to happen at `npm install` time instead of `git clone`. I would need something like this in a pip package or composer package if I want this to run on python or php project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the husky dependency is installed (through `npm install`, `npm add husky`, `yarn install`, ...) git hooks are created/updated in the .git/hooks directory. If the hook is triggered through a git command a script from husky is triggered that will execute a command based on the package manager you used for the installation. If you use npm `npx --no-install husky-run $hookName "$gitParams"` is executed. That command looks into your configuration and executes the command defined for the hook there.

It's like a proxy for git hooks. The proxy is installed once and executed every time by a normal git hook. If it is executed it looks into the configuration and executes the commands defined there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is something interesting, installing stuff run arbitrary code, which is a potencial security risk. I asked because I tried to reproduce this behavior with pure git, but it is impossible. At last I can't find a way to get hooks copied to .git/hooks at clone, so I put they on readme and let the user install it manually.

Thanks again

Comment: @geckos: yes, there is a definite security risk. But then again: checking out and building *any* software is a potential security risk because almost all build system allow executing arbitrary external commands (i.e. arbitrary code execution). So you shouldn't be building untrusted software anyway.

Answer (score 21):

As of version 5 `husky` uses git's [`core.hooksPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) [`git config core.hooksPath .husky`](https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/d022b2ba05c5a9d35a81a632614d43920e3849ec/src/commands/install.ts#L41) to be exact. This is done in `husky install` step.

Since `.husky` folder created by `husky install` contains `pre-commit` script, it will be run before commit.
By default it will have `npm test` in it but you can edit it to your wish.

You can do something similar in any project. Just add `.githooks` folder and hook files inside it(check .git/hooks for sample files). But you have to run `git config core.hooksPath .githooks` while cloning the repo(or setting up hooks for the first time). You can have some init script to do that.
`npm` has [`scripts.prepare`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) which can run commands on `npm install` which is `husky install` in this case.